# Vague Error when running SSIS package locally: Hresult: 0x80070057 Description: "The parameter is incorrect.". Limiting to 1 record runs fine

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Full error text: [Get.... [3397]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80070057.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80070057  Description: "The parameter is incorrect.".

When I run this package locally this error comes up. I am not convinced it has anything to do with the first step as the query it calls works fine. It also runs perfectly if I limit the query to a single record. I can change the record it uses and it continues to work. If I try to limit the query to two individually working records it fails with this error.

I've deleted and recreated multiple steps with no success.

The package contains many different steps including data conversions, unpivots, conditional splits, sorts, merges, gets, derived columns, unions, multicasts and writing to DB

Any clues on what to look for would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After working on figuring this out for several day and finally posting here I adjusted the DefaultBufferSize in the properties of the task from 10,485,760 bytes to  20,971,520 bytes and increased the DefaultBufferMaxRows to 100,000 up from 10,000. After making those adjustments the error disappeared.

DefaultBufferSize from 10,485,760 bytes -> 20,971,520 bytes
DefaultBufferMaxRows from 10,000 -> 100,000